# SQL Query for filter panel not working good

Tags: php, mysql

Hey I was making a college internship portal project using PHP but getting stuck at this point where for all relevant and irrelevant details from the filter table the page is showing results!

The filter table asks following details regarding:
1. Category - where the category of internship is to be provided
2. Location - the location where he desires to do the internship
3. The starting date
4. Work from home or not
5. fifth is a specific keyword search to find all relevant data related to the keyword

PHP code is

```
<?php       

        if (isset($_POST['search'])) 
        {
            $category = trim($_POST['cat']);
            $location = trim($_POST['loc']);
            $start = $_POST['start-date'];
            $starting = strtotime($start);
            $duration = $_POST['duration'];
            $work = '';
            $key = $_POST['key-srch'];

                if (isset($_POST['work-home'])) 
                {
                    $work = $_POST['work-home'];
                }

                elseif (!empty($duration)) 
                {
                    if (!is_numeric($duration))
                    {
                        $err_msg = "Please enter a number upto 6 !";
                        $code = '1';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $sql = " SELECT * 
                              FROM is_internship
                              WHERE 
                              (`profile/category` LIKE '$category' OR `location` LIKE '$location' OR `start_date` >= '$starting') 
                              OR (`duration` LIKE '$duration' OR `job-type` LIKE '$work') 
                              OR (`profile/category` LIKE '%{$key}%' OR `job-type` LIKE '%{$key}%' 
                              OR `part-time` LIKE '%{$key}%' 
                              OR `location` LIKE '%{$key}%' )";

                    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                        if ($query == TRUE && mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
                        {
                            echo mysqli_num_rows($query);
                            $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_BOTH);


                        }

                }
        }


?>
```

The whole code works well except the sql query which i suppose to be wrong at this point of time... Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Comment: Yaa i m working on that too!!

Comment: You should build the query dynamically and parameterize it. Are all the fields required?

Comment: yes, all the fields are required! I am unaware of making dynamic query